# How to inspect defined constraints in python?

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools

Is there any way to inspect model and see what constraints have been defined?

For instance, https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/sudoku_sat.py defines the following:

```
# AllDifferent on rows.
for i in line:
    model.AddAllDifferent(grid[(i, j)] for j in line)
```

Does this create some observable entity in **model** (e.g. i number of entity-constraints)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan the underlying cp_model protobuf.

see model.Proto()